# How to add 1 millisecond to a timestamp in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have to add 1 millisecond to a timestamp.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT cr_time+'0000-00-00 00:00:00.001' FROM foo.bar
```

which returns

```
Error: [SQL0182] A date, time, or timestamp expression not valid.
SQLState:  42816
ErrorCode: -182
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT  TIMESTAMPADD(1,1,CR_TIME) FROM foo.bar
```

which returns

```
Error: [SQL0204] TIMESTAMPADD in *LIBL type *N not found.
SQLState:  42704
ErrorCode: -204
```

What's the correct way to add 1 millisecond to a timestamp?

Answer (score 9):

After all I found this solution:

```
SELECT CR_TIME + 1000 MICROSECONDS FROM foo.bar
```